# Android shift key listener

Tags: android

I need to know when the user hits the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (Soft Keyboard) in my EditText.  currently, I'm using an addTextChangedListener, but it isn't called when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed (though it is when any other key is pressed)

What can I do to know when the user hits the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key?

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the example below can help you

```
//while your activity class should be implementing OnKeyListener like below
//public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnKeyListener { ....}
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

then by overriding the method of key listener you can sense the shift key

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.myEditTextId:
    if(keyCode==59)//59 is shift's keycode
    //do your stuff here against pressing shift key
    break;
    }
    }
```

you can get android key code list here http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2009/04/android-keycodes-list.html

Answer (score 5):

You have to use [View.OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

```
edit1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.isShiftPressed())
      {

       }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Does this work with the soft keyboard?  It's not working for me :-/

Comment: @DigitalHazard - I'm not aware of the situation you have. Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282214/onkeylistener-not-working-on-virtual-keyboard